# Доброго времени суток! Прошу о помощи!

Tags: python

[image: Здравствуйте! В данном деле я самовар, прошу помощи! Решил написать калькулятор, а это чудо не работает должным образом, а именно: после ввода второго числа в действие сразу же приступает оператор else и программа автоматически завершается, и калькулятор не калькулирует]

Здравствуйте! В данном деле я самовар, прошу помощи! Решил написать калькулятор, а это чудо не работает должным образом, а именно: после ввода второго числа в действие сразу же приступает оператор else и программа автоматически завершается, и калькулятор не калькулирует

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1260664/edit))

Comment: Код - текстом. Название и тест вопроса - по существу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. для начала ввод (который всегда текстовой) надо бы перевести в числа, например:

   ```
    a = int(input("..."))
   ```
2. результат будет тоже числом, а значит складывать со строкой нельзя, вообще используйте f-строки:

   ```
    print(f"Result: {c}")
   ```
3. поскольку вы сейчас работаете со строками (см. п.1), то `a + b`, означает конкатенацию строк `"10" + "20" = "1020"`, а вот для `a - b` операция не определена и будет ошибка